# What is this juniper called?

Tags: identification

I have 4 of these that i plan on using as a hedge but i don't know how far apart to plant them since im clueless as to how large these things can get. [image]

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to be certain of variety because there are so many which have been created in the last few years, but whichever variety it may be, its definitely a prostrate one, evidenced by its growth habit. If you only want a low hedge, it'll be fine, but it is likely to remain up to about a foot high for the next ten years, possibly reaching 1-2 feet at maturity, with a spread sideways of between 4-6 feet.

Prostrate junipers like this are not ideal as hedges because their growth habit is to sprawl outwards, though they do make useful ground cover; any pruning should be restricted to once a year, and even then only a light prune, so if you wanted a more formal, higher hedge, this is not really a suitable choice.

The most similar variety I know of without trawling the internet for hours is *Juniperus communis depressa aurea* https://plants.ces.ncsu.edu/plants/juniperus-communis-depressa-aurea/

Comment: Oh dear. I wish i had known earlier. The other 3 that i have were in bigger containers (7 gallon) when i brought them home. They measure 20 inches from the base up but i guess they wouldn't serve the purpose that i had intended them for which was to have a 3 ft tall hedge at the front. So sad right now..

Comment: Ooh, sorry... but there's a lesson in this, isn't there? Always check the latin name of the plant you want to buy so you can find out its height and spread and other growing information first.

Comment: Yes lesson well learned. If only plants came with tags where im at cause its so difficult to distinguish between all these different types since they all look the same. Old gold, sea of gold, gold coast, gold star and the one you've mentioned amoung many.

Comment: That's terrible, not knowing what you're buying - I assume asking the seller what the plant is doesn't get a sensible answer either...

Comment: Oh definitely. I'm so glad i found this site. Also, its not just the nurseries but the whole of the city's landscape. All our old trees are dying and no one seems to care or is knowledgeable enough for that matter to carry out a proper replantation scheme.

Comment: There are now several Plant Identifier apps available for phones, both IoS and Android - I've no idea how useful or accurate they are, they might be really bad for all I know, but in your situation, it might be better than nothing, some mentioned here https://awesomejelly.com/8-best-apps-identify-unknown-plants-flowers-2/. I suspect, though, they may  not be that good at recognising a particular variety of a plant such as the one you're asking about here

Comment: Your absolutely right. I have one installed in my phone. It'll help you identify a plant but not when it comes to different varieties within the species. It wont tell you the kind of rose you've got other then it being a rose.

Comment: Not terribly useful then, really.